# How to redeploy a release in Azure Pipelines Pull request?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

A release has failed because of a scripting error in one of the tasks:

> [error]Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

I've resolved the issue and when I release from the build the release succeeds but the status in the PR still states:

> *** Release failed

If I click on the failed release I can do a redeploy but it's still using the same scripts as before.

How can I update the status of a linked release in a PR?

Comment: you can simple remove the release and create a new one or you open the failed release and edit it to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Re-Deploy is running the exact release without your changes, you need to queue again the PR build:

[image]

After that the new release will be queued and the status will be succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

> If I click on the failed release I can do a redeploy but it's still using the same scripts as before.

This is an expected behavior. The option `Redeploy` is used to re-deploy the **same Artifacts** with different definition settings.

When we select the Redeploy option, we will notice that the Artifacts are still **the last time we released** not the latest Artifacts:

[image]

So, if you want the update the status of a linked release in a PR, you could create a new PR to queue the new build with your changes, or you can select the `Queue build` option like Shayki answered.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why is it needed to run the build again? The build is fine, the release process wasn't.